# Are there tools for assisting with the math involved in Fire Emblem d20?

Tags: tool-recommendation

I'm looking into trying "[Fire Emblem d20](http://fed20.wikidot.com/beginning-fed20)," a free RPG which is almost a direct port of the Fire Emblem Video Game. However, it seems there is a lot of math for even basic actions, so I'm looking for a way to expedite those calculations. Obviously, excel could do this, but I'm looking for tools with a little more dedication to this. What tools are available for assisting me in dealing with this math?

Comment: I've edited this to provide a direct question of _what_ you're looking for. A question of "any suggestions?" or "any tools?" without a "for doing X" in there is going to set off peoples' too-broad detectors. Since overcoming the math pervasive in the system seems to be your issue, I've made that the X.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand what you are looking for. Do you need help figuring out how things work in the d20 system (OGL)? Perhaps you could give examples of what math exactly do you mean when you refer to "basic actions".

Comment: @Argamae For one attack in fire emblem d20, you do 5 different calculations which require input of the attacking and defending characters' statistics. I don't know why the d20 is there, as it does not function like other d20 systems.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry as it seems I was mistaken. Just read up on FED20. Although it is called "Fire Emblem D20" it does not seem to share much of the original mechanic of the D&D d20 system. The attack mechanic is nothing like D&D so I can't help you there. Just commented this because others might be confused, too.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, my answer depends a bit on how much knowledge you have in programming and scripting.

The calculations could easily be done with Excel, the google doc spread sheet, or Matlab.

Matlab might take the most scripting knowledge, but you can end up with a small very easy to use applet for all of your players.

Comment: Thanks for the try. I thought of programming something in python or java, but that may be more work than a sheet. If I had me a matlab license, it could eat up a lot of those calculations no problem!

Comment: If you're a university student, you can get a Matlab license pretty much free. I wish I could be more help, but I'm only a math major without a lot of free time.